# Does an enclitic -que with an interrogative pronoun ever mean "and"?

Tags: interrogative, enclitic

Enclitic -que generally means "and" in Latin.

It's quite common to see -que paired with the interrogative pronoun *quis/quid* (as well as other pronouns like it, e.g. the relative pronouns *qui/quae/quod*), but this generally changes the meaning. See, for instance, [*Allen & Greenough* §151(g)](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/relative-interrogative-and-indefinite-pronouns):

> The enclitic particle ***-que*** added to the interrogative gives a *universal*
>
> - ***quisque*** every one
> - ***uterque*** each of two, or both.

My question: **Are there any cases where *-que* paired with an interrogative pronoun keeps its usual sense of "and"?** Could I say, for instance:

> Quis es quidque facis?

meaning:

> Who are you and what are you doing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Quidque velit" seems to mean "et quid velit" in this line from Ovid:

> Quos omnes acie postquam Saturnia torva
> vidit et ante omnes Ixiona, rursus ab illo
> Sisyphon adspiciens “cur hic e fratribus” inquit
> “perpetuas patitur poenas, Athamanta superbum
> regia dives habet, qui me cum coniuge semper
> sprevit?” **et exponit causas odiique viaeque**,
> **quidque velit**: quod vellet, erat, ne regia Cadmi
> staret, et in facinus traherent Athamanta sorores.

Also *quidque* in *Digesta Iustiniani* 48.19.6.pr.6:

> inquirunt, quid sit, quod allegare principi uelint, quidque quod pro salute ipsius habeant dicere, post quae aut sustinent poenam aut non sustinent.

Actually, I found it difficult to find clear and unambiguous examples. (I think questions with multiple question words (of any form) are fairly rare in Latin, as they are in English, so that could partly explain why it is hard to find examples.) But
in general, it is possible for *-que* to be used as a coordinating conjunction even in cases where it creates homophony with another word ending in *-que*. So I think "Quis es quidque facis?" could be used with the sense "Who are you and what are you doing?"

When attached to a relative pronoun, *-que* just has its normal usual sense of "and", e.g.

> nam quanti refert te ei nec recte dicere
>
> qui nihili faciat **quique** infitias non eat? = [et qui infitias non eat?]

(*Plautus*, Pseudolus 1086)

> praedicationem non me praeterit, si, quem desideramus
> agricolam **quemque** describemus = [et quem describemus]

(Columella, *De Re Rustica* 1.pr.28.6)

I think examples of relative pronoun + coordinating *-que* are not that rare.

Comment: Wonderful finds!